# arcpy Refresh element attributes during code execution

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to adjust an element text size iteratively until the element is a certain size. I had a script to do this in ArcMap that worked well, but replicating in ArcGIS Pro isn't providing the same functionality. This code deals with a text element `t_elm` and a graphic element `g_elm`. The text size is reduced until `t_elm` fits inside `g_elm`. In ArcMap, the elementWidth and elementHeight updated during the while loop. In ArcGIS Pro, these attributes are never updated, so the while loop doesn't end.

Relevant snippet:

```py
#start at size 50, reduce text to 95% of graphic max dimension
g_elmHeight = g_elm.elementHeight * 0.95
g_elmWidth = g_elm.elementWidth * 0.95
x = 50

while t_elm.elementWidth > g_elmWidth or t_elm.elementHeight > g_elmHeight:
  elm.textSize = x
  x = x - 0.05
```

Entire code block:

```py
def AdjustSize(elmName):

#Reference the current project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
layout = aprx.activeView

#look for text element
arcpy.AddMessage("Looking for text element " + elmName)

t_elm = layout.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT",elmName + " text")[0]
g_elm = layout.listElements("GRAPHIC_ELEMENT",elmName)[0]

#if statement executes if a match has been found
##if  g_elm <>[]:
if g_elm and t_elm:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Found: "+elmName+"....Resizing...")
        #Sets the target height and width based on graphic element
        g_elmHeight = g_elm.elementHeight * 0.95
        g_elmWidth = g_elm.elementWidth * 0.95
        arcpy.AddMessage(g_elmHeight)
        arcpy.AddMessage(g_elmWidth)
        
        #set initial font size to 50
        x = 50
        t_elm.textSize=x
        
        #Loop until targets reached
        while t_elm.elementWidth > g_elmWidth or t_elm.elementHeight > g_elmHeight:
            elm.textSize = x
            x = x - 0.05
            arcpy.AddMessage("...Resizing " + elmName + " "+str(x))
            arcpy.AddMessage(str(t_elm.elementWidth) +" "+ str(t_elm.elementHeight))

        #Centers text with graphic, assumes default lower left anchor point
        t_elm.elementPositionY = (g_elm.elementPositionY + 0.5 * g_elm.elementHeight - t_elm.elementHeight * 0.5)
        t_elm.elementPositionX = (g_elm.elementPositionX + 0.5 * g_elm.elementWidth - t_elm.elementWidth * 0.5)

        #clean up
        del t_elm,g_elm,x,elmWidth,elmHeight

else:#inform user that there is no graphic with the same name
  arcpy.AddMessage("No matching elements for " + elmName)
```

Comment: Nothing in your while loop is changing anything about  `t_elm` so that's why it stays in the loop. Also `elm` is not declare anywhere?

Comment: Great shame.. that's what I get for renaming variables. Thank you.